# Forcing embedded Acrobat viewer to capture mouse wheel

Tags: c#, winforms, acrobat, mousewheel, acrobat-sdk

I have an embedded Acrobat viewer in a C# winform application. 
The viewer is in a tab page `tabPage1` in a tab control

I use the code from this answer: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159475/1543816)

```
CAcroAVDoc acroExchAVDoc;
CAcroPDDoc pdDoc; 

void CreatePdfViewerAndOpenFile(string pdfFile)
{
    short AV_DOC_VIEW = 2;
    short PDUseBookmarks = 3;
    short AVZoomFitWidth = 2;

    Type AcroExch_AVDoc = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AcroExch.AVDoc");
    acroExchAVDoc = (Acrobat.CAcroAVDoc)Activator.CreateInstance(AcroExch_AVDoc);
    bool ok = acroExchAVDoc.OpenInWindowEx(pdfFile, tabPage1.Handle.ToInt32(), AV_DOC_VIEW, -1, 0, PDUseBookmarks, AVZoomFitWidth, 0, 0, 0);
    pdDoc = (CAcroPDDoc)acroExchAVDoc.GetPDDoc();
}
```

I want to force the viewer to capture the mouse wheel so the file scrolls.

When I switch to another window and back to the application, I find the tab page name focused, and the file doesn't scroll.

I use Adobe Acrobat DC.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Does the viewer scroll when it is focused?

If yes just set the Focus back on the viewer when your Form gets active again.

You can always send WM_MOUSEWHEEL to the viewer. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326718/how-to-scroll-window-in-other-process-with-win32api)

Comment: How can I set the focus back to the viewer? That's the problem. I can't find any methods to do so.

Comment: if you have the handle of the control/window you want to focus (it seems you do) you can p/invoke. try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28604906/711061.